# Java: interface を implements した class を 探す方法

Tags: java

interface を 使用 した class を取得したい

```
  public interface IExtension {
    String getName();

    String getVersion();
  }

  public class AExtension implements IExtension {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "A";
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
      return "1.0.0";
    }
  }

  public class BExtension implements IExtension {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "B";
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
      return "1.0.0";
    }
  }
```

Comment: 実行時なのか、静的なソースコード解析の話（IDE上）なのかを明記すべきですね。

Answer (score 2):

Javaの実行時に　という意味だと、[reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)のgetSubTypesOfメソッドを使って取得する方法があります。

```
package com.detect.subclasses;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Set;

public class DetectSubClassesTest {

    @Test
    public void getSubclasses() {
        Set<Class<? extends IExtension>> subTypes =
                new Reflections("com.detect.subclasses").getSubTypesOf(IExtension.class);

        assert subTypes.size() == 2;

        subTypes.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public interface IExtension {
        String getName();

        String getVersion();
    }

    public static class AExtension implements IExtension {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "A";
        }

        @Override
        public String getVersion() {
            return "1.0.0";
        }
    }

    public static class BExtension implements IExtension {

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "B";
        }

        @Override
        public String getVersion() {
            return "1.0.0";
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
class com.detect.subclasses.DetectSubClassesTest$AExtension
class com.detect.subclasses.DetectSubClassesTest$BExtension
```

Answer (score 0):

`implements IExtension`のキーワードでソースディレクトリをgrepするか、IDEの検索機能（Type Hierarchyなど）を利用すればいいと思います。